# Strip anything after and including first instance of non letter

Tags: php

Is it possible using PHP to strip everything from a string after and including the first 'non' letter?

E.g.

`Blue Bayou (1954)` becomes `Blue Bayou`

`Hello World: 1234` becomes `Hello World`

Comment: Please, we already have a tagging system! Don't write tags in titles. Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's doable with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) as follows:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w\s].*$/', "", $str);
```

The `/[^\w\s].+$/` is the small [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) micro-program. It looks for the first character that is neither a letter `\w` or a space `\s` and matches anything else `.*` after that.

And `""` is the empty string which replaces the matched parts. Note that a space after `Bayou` will be kept in example 1. (Wanted to keep the example short. But see the comment! ha)

Comment: Probably `/\s*...` to have the `rtrim` effect, or just a `trim` afterwards :)